# Error Visual Studio ArgumentException was thrown when using ado.net EF adding object into table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

So I using Visual Studio to connect to a local oracle db, which I import from a dump file before. I can see the values from the record inside the table just fine. But when I try to create an object and add it back into the table, I have the argument exception occur in system.data.entity.dll Additional Information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 118. I been looking around and can't find the solution for my case.... Is this an issue with connection or?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static SPEntities SPContext = new SPEntities;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            runTest();
        }            
        void runTest()
        {
            ORI newOrObject = new ORI();
            newOrObject.ORIID = 15852;

            SPContext.ORIs.Add(newOrObject);
            SPContext.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 118.
```

Comment: Rather than a vague description of the code, just show it. It's very difficult to identify a problem with your code without seeing it in the first place.

Comment: I added new information

Comment: Found out that there is another error. Saying something like cannot use the context while the context is being created.